# ¿Es posible obtener metadatos de una consulta con JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

para obtener los datos, no tengo problema, puedo leerlos y gestionarlos, para ello he usado:

```
select * from MiTabla;
```

Y para leerlo:

```
em = emf.createEntityManager();     
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * from MiTabla");
List<Object[]> listaDatos = query.getResultList();
```

Ahora bien, lo que necesito es obtener los nombres de los campos de dicha consulta, lo complicado, es que la estructura de la consulta no está linkeada con JPA, es decir, el resultado no es una estructura de una tabla linkeada.

Por ello, no se si es posible obtener los metadatos desde una consulta, es decir, así como obtengo los datos en sí, poder obtener los metadatos. Si alguien saber algo sobre el tema, pues genial.

Antes de finalizar, uso EclipseLink y he encontrado esta respuesta, pero no se como aplicarla.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517111/jpa-how-to-access-query-meta-data

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes recuperar los datos en un mapa y después acceder al nombre de los campos y valores de esta forma:

```
String strQuery="select * from MiTabla";
Query query = em.createQuery(strQuery);
query.setHint("eclipselink.result-type", "Map");
query.setHint("eclipselink.cursor.scrollable", true);

ScrollableCursor cursor = (ScrollableCursor) query.getSingleResult();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DatabaseRecord record = (DatabaseRecord) cursor.next();
    Vector<DatabaseField> fields = record.getFields();

    for(DatabaseField field : fields) {
        String name = field.getName();
        Object value = record.getValues(field);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! ^^ Es lo que buscaba, muchas gracias ^^