# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de las columnas de una consulta, createNativeQuery en Jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

```
String query = select + users + valor + "tt2.codigo from \n" + "    TipoTipificacion tt2\n"
            + "/* aqui comienza tabla 1*/\n" + "LEFT OUTER JOIN\n"
            + " (select t.TipoTipificacion_idTipoTipi,tt.tipo,COUNT(tt.tipo) as suma,ll2.campaign,\n"
            + " u.idUsuarios    ,CONCAT(u.nombre,' ',u.apellido) as Asesor\n" + "from\n"
            + " (SELECT  max(tipi.idTipificacion) maxxid\n" + " from\n"
            + " (select idTipificacion,Llamada_idLlamada as maxid,TipoTipificacion_idTipoTipi from Tipificacion GROUP BY Llamada_idLlamada) as tipi\n"
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN Llamada ll on tipi.maxid=ll.idLlamada\n"
            + " GROUP BY ll.cedulaCliente) as tipi2\n"
            + " INNER JOIN Tipificacion t on tipi2.maxxid=t.idTipificacion\n"
            + " INNER JOIN Llamada ll2 on t.Llamada_idLlamada=ll2.idLlamada\n"
            + " LEFT  OUTER JOIN TipoTipificacion tt on t.TipoTipificacion_idTipoTipi=tt.idTipoTipi\n"
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN (select count(ll3.cedulaCliente) as suma,ll3.cedulaCliente from Llamada ll3 GROUP BY ll3.cedulaCliente) as contar on ll2.cedulaCliente=contar.cedulaCliente\n"
            + "INNER JOIN Usuario u on ll2.Usuario_idUsuarios=u.idUsuarios\n"
            + " GROUP BY tt.tipo,u.idUsuarios,ll2.campaign ORDER BY ll2.campaign,u.apellido asc) as tabla1 on tt2.idTipoTipi = tabla1.TipoTipificacion_idTipoTipi\n"
            + "/* aqui termina tabla1 */\n" + call + "\n" + " GROUP BY tt2.tipo";

    Query q5 = em.createNativeQuery(query);
    List<Object[]> list = q5.getResultList();
```

tengo la anterior consulta me devuelve los valores correctamente,Pero quiero obtener el nombre de las columnas de ese resultado, ejm:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado que quiero seria el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo tenía la misma duda, si usas JDBC, esta es una solución:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53599/es-posible-obtener-metadatos-de-una-consulta-con-jpa

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando JPA 2.0 puedes lo que podrías hacer es definir un bean correspondiente a una tupla del resultado, de modo que en vez de invocar a `em.createNativeQuery(query);`invoques a `em.createNativeQuery(String s, Class aClass)` donde `aClass` es una clase POJO que representa el resultado de tu consulta y es una entidad.

De esa forma obtendrías un listado de Usuarios o Clientes (el nombre que le pongas a tu entity) y no `List<Object>` y entonces sabrias a que columna refiere el valor.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM una_tabla", Cliente.class);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Cliente> results= (List<Cliente>) query.getResultList();
```

Si por alguna razón no puedes crear un bean que represente el resultado de la consulta (quizá tu implementacion no es un POJO o tienes alguna otra limitación) puedes agregar [Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) y utilizar [SimpleJdbcDaoSupport.getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForList(nativeQuery)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Este metodo en lugar de retornar `List<Object>` retorna un listado de mapeos entre nombre de columna y valor.